# Layout inspector error. In emulator the app doesnt update the old layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, layout-inspector

I am getting unknown error in my layout inspector. It wouldn't be a problem if my app, when running under the emulator doesn't load the layouts at all. I'm using android O with support library 26.0.0-beta2. Gradle finds no errors. Heres the log:

```
    Rendering failed with a known bug. Please try a rebuild.  The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ViewBackgroundHelper   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:46)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:73)   `at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:66)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:52)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:46)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createNavBar(Layout.java:284)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:140) Copy stack to clipboard`
```

I tried rebuilding, refreshing, clearing the cache, changing the whole layout's code. I feel that the problem is not in the layouts'xml, because I also tried copying the layout from tutorial site. Same problem.

Comment: Did you try the `Build > Rebuild project` as it suggested?

Comment: Many times. I even restarted Android studio several times in hope it will be fixed.

Comment: Perhaps it will work when Android O hits some real devices or when you stop using a beta version of the support library?

Answer (score 3):

changed the support library to 26 alpha, problem solved

Comment: Can you please specify the version that worked for you?  Was it 26.0.0-alpha?